# Silverlight: How to bind to a resource that is defined as a usercontrol resource in code

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a string value that i have defined as a resource in a user controls' constructor

```
public void usercontrolClas()
{
    this.Resources.Add("stringState", "foo");
}
```

I am trying to access this string as a StaticResource in the XAML of a child usercontrol of the above usercontrol.

```
<Button Content={.... ,ConverterParameter={StaticResource stringState}"/>
```

However this doesnt work. Its working if i add the resource to Application.Resources, but I have some state thats is instance specific to the usercontrol and hence has to be scoped to the usercontrol. Anyde

Answer (score 0):

`{StaticResource}` won't work here. Once you bind it using `{StaticResource}` changes in resource won't be reflected. And in your case, the resource does not even exist until you create it after `UserControl`'s `InitializeComponent()` method.

To make this work, you will need `{DynamicResource}`. But, unfortunately, it is not available in `WP7 Silverlight` right now.

Other way you could go is creating an `Attached Property` or a `Custom Behavior` to work around this limitation.

### Tutorials on Behaviors:

- [Silverlight Behaviors and Triggers](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42959/Silverlight-Behaviors-and-Triggers-Making-a-True-B.aspx)
- [Using Behaviors to enable MouseWheel in Full Screen and Out-of-browser](http://blogs.esri.com/Dev/blogs/silverlightwpf/archive/2009/08/14/Using-Behaviors-to-enable-MouseWheel-in-Full-Screen-and-Out_2D00_of_2D00_browser.aspx)
- [Silverlight 3 Drag Behavior](http://joel.neubeck.net/2009/07/silverlight-3-drag-behavior/)